# How do I show some text and hide an image with hover, with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

When hovering over a side-info-panel (`.popup-hover-section`), I want the info-img to hide(`.popup-hover-div p`), and at the same time show the text in `.show-span`.

```
<section class="popup-hover-section">
                    <div class="popup-hover-div"><p></p><span class="show-span">Hidden text, but only until I am hovered over, and the whole section is shown! And my brother paragraph is hidden! :)</span></div>
</section>
```

````
.popup-hover-section {
        height: 30%;
        width: 65px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0%;
        top: 30%;
        background-color: #111;
        color: #eee;
        border-radius: 40px 0 0 40px;
        transition: width 1s;
        transition-property: border-radius, width;
        box-shadow: 7px 7px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        z-index: 20;
    }
    
    .popup-hover-div p {
        padding: 32px 32px 32px 32px;
        display: flex;
        align-self: center;
        background: url(images/information.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    
    .show-span {
        /*I want to show the text inside this one, and when I do, the p-img should not show anymore*/
    }
    
    .popup-hover-div p:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .popup-hover-section:hover {
        background-image: linear-gradient(147deg, #FFE53B 0%, #FF2525 74%);
        transition-duration: 1.3s;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.89, 0.32, 1.28);
        width: 400px;
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to catch the hover over the container (`.popup-hover-section`) and then continue the selector from there to style the elements within.

```
.popup-hover-div:hover .show-span{ //styles }

.popup-hover-div:hover p img{ //styles }
```

I trust you can tweak it from here, but if you need further assistance give a shout.

```css
.popup-hover-section {
  height: 30%;
  width: 65%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1%;
  top: 30%;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #eee;
  border-radius: 40px 0 0 40px;
  transition: width 1s;
  transition-property: border-radius, width;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 20;
}

.popup-hover-div p {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.show-span {
  /*I want to show the text inside this one, and when I do, the p-img should not show anymore*/
  color: transparent;
}
.popup-hover-div:hover .show-span{
  color: lightblue;
}

.popup-hover-div:hover p img{
  opacity: 0;
}
p, span{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 1;
}
span{
  top:30px;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="popup-hover-section">
  <div class="popup-hover-div">
    <p><img src="https://placekitten.com/380/100" /></p>
    <span class="show-span">Hidden text, but only until I am hovered over, and the whole section is shown! And my brother paragraph is hidden! :)</span></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hellooo

```
.show-span {
  opacity: 0;
}

.popup-hover-section:hover .show-span {
  /*I want to show the text inside this one, and when I do, the p-img should not show anymore*/
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 1.3s;
}
```

I think this is the one you are looking for. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: Yes, thanks. This worked well!

(not sure how to post like code on a comments comment, using `code` as it says.)


`.popup-hover-div:hover p {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.popup-hover-div:hover .show-span {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}

.show-span {
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 40px;
    font-family: 'IM Fell French';
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 400px;
}`